# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass spree app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am getting the below error when I am trying to login to `spree admin` at `localhost:3000/admin`.

> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

```
   <li class="dropdown ">
       <% max_level = Spree::Config[:max_level_in_taxons_menu] || 1 %>
              <a  class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Shop</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <% @taxonomies.each do |taxonomy| %>
           <% cache [I18n.locale, taxonomy, max_level, @taxon] do %>
           <% if taxonomy.name =='Categories' %>
           <% taxons = taxonomy.root.children.map do |taxon| %>
           <li class="dropdown ">
            <%= link_to(taxon.name, seo_url(taxon), class: 'dropdown-toggle', 'data-toggle'=>"dropdown") %>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Black</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Green</a></li>
       </ul>
        </li>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
    </li>
```

The above code is where it is giving me error. Which I have in header partial. It gives me proper homepage when I go to `localhost:3000`, but gives an error when I try to login to admin. The header which I want to have is coming properly. But unable to login to admin.

Please help

Comment: do you set @taxonomies when you try to go to ulr /admin ?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you're trying to say

Comment: in your partial code above you are looping through @taxonomies. From what I see that is the place throwing the error. So it may be that when you are trying to access /admin taxonomies variable is not set. while when you are accessing http://localhost what ever controller you are accessing through your root route  you have taxonomies variable set.

Comment: What version of spree are you using? Have you run one of `rake db:seed` or `rake db:migrate` yet?

Comment: yes, I am using `3.0.5` and I have run the migrations